# Trigram search with operators not selecting the correct result set

Tags: postgresql, indexing, trigram

I have a use case where a substring search is required within a string provided by the client. The substrings to match are present in a `match` table within the `value` column.

```
CREATE TABLE match (
    value varchar not null,
    type  varchar not null,
);
```

A GiST trigram index has been created on the `value` column.

```
CREATE INDEX trgm_idx ON match USING GIST (value gist_trgm_ops(siglen=32));
```

For the purpose of this question let us assume that `match` contains the following two rows:

| value | type |
| --- | --- |
| some_str | type_a |
| 12345678 | type_b |

I would like to understand how exactly the `<<%` works for strict word similarity.

The query below:

```
SELECT value,strict_word_similarity(value, 'file some_str 01') as sml
FROM match
WHERE 'file some_str 01' <<% value
ORDER BY sml DESC, value;
```

returns the following:

| value | sml |
| --- | --- |
| some_str | 1 |

Similarly, the query with `12345678` returns the correct `match` row:

```
SELECT value,strict_word_similarity(value, 'file 12345678 01') as sml
FROM match
WHERE 'file 12345678 01' <<% value
ORDER BY sml DESC, value;
```

| value | sml |
| --- | --- |
| 12345678 | 1 |

However, if both the search terms are included in the query, no results are returned:

```
SELECT value,strict_word_similarity(value, 'file some_str 12345678 01') as sml
FROM match
WHERE 'file some_str 12345678 01' <<% value
ORDER BY sml DESC, value;

No rows returned
```

As per my expectations both the matching rows should be returned.

I would like to know what exactly is preventing the matching from happening.

Interestingly, if `strict_word_similarity(value, 'file some_str 12345678 01')` is used in the `WHERE` clause instead of `<<%`, both rows are indeed returned. However, the GiST index is no longer used by the query.

Is it possible to have multiple matches while also using the index as defined above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function and your operator work in opposite directions.  The operator that matches strict_word_similarity argument ordering is `%>>`, not `<<%`.

With the operator you are using, neither of the rows are returned because they have scores which don't meet the default  pg_trgm.strict_word_similarity_threshold value.  If you use the other operator, both will be returned.

Comment: I see. The trouble is that `%>>` doesn't use index anymore. Would it be possible to also use the index somehow?